# Solution to equation (is it possible?)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, galois-theory, factoring

After stumbling through some dense fog of algebra, I have come across the following problem - any help would be much appreciated!

I'm currently trying to solve the following equation, but my efforts to date have been inconsequential. I was wondering whether anyone had some suggestions on how to proceed with solving the following equation for $x$? Clearly, in the case where $w_3 = 0$, one can easily solve a quadratic equation, but, if possible, I'd ideally like a general method for solving the equation rather than thinking about this on a case by case basis (since the $w_i$ are themselves functions of many parameters which ideally shouldn't be restricted to special cases).

The equation I'm trying to solve for $x$ is: $$a_1x^2 + a_2x + a_3x^{1-\frac{1}{\alpha}} + a_4 = 0$$

where $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4 > 0$, and $\alpha > 0$ is a fixed parameter.

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't a polynomial equation if one of the terms is $w_3x^{1-1/\alpha}$

Comment: For what are you wanting to solve?

Comment: Is $\alpha$ a rational number?

Comment: @hardmath

If we could solve it for the rational case, that'd be good, but in general, $\alpha$ is a positive real number.

Comment: @WilliamElliot For $x$. :-)

Comment: If $a=1$, you have a quadratic equation. In the general case, it is a transcendental equation. Because it depends on $x$ and $e^{(1-\frac{1}{a})\ln(x)}$ which are algebraically independent, the equation cannot be solved by transforming it by elementary operations you can derive from the equation.

Comment: @IV_ I expected as much! Thanks :-)

Comment: If $\alpha\neq 1$ is a rational number, you get an irrational equation. If $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ and $a_4$ are algebraic, the solutions of this irrational equations are algebraic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For arbitrary (irrational) $\alpha$ there is an obstacle to solving the equation beyond the mere fact that it is not a polynomial equation.  The coefficients $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$ are assumed to be positive, so that there are no changes-in-sign in the equation and Descartes' rule (generalized) tells us there are no positive roots.

But on the other hand $x^{1-\frac{1}{\alpha}}$ is only well-defined for positive $x$ when $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is irrational.  So putting these two observations together would say there is not even a possibility of numerical approximation of a root (no positive root exists and it is unclear what complex root might be meaningful).

Comment: @IV_: The response given by OP to my asking about rationality of $\alpha$ suggests an interest in solutions  for a continuous parameter rather than for an isolated rational value.  So I did not pursue the idea of a related polynomial equation further.